Using GeoTools the geometry field is not updated
I try update feature geometry in GeoServer using GeoTools library in my application, but was not success.
public static boolean updateGeometry(String typeName, Geometry geometry, String sid, String wfsVersion) {
    try {
        WFSDataStore dataStore = getDataStore(wfsVersion);
    
        SimpleFeatureType sft = dataStore.getSchema(typeName);
    
        QName qName = dataStore.getRemoteTypeName(sft.getName());
        String geomColumn = getGeomColumn(dataStore, qName);
        Filter idFilter = ff.id(ff.featureId(sid));
    
        return updateTransaction(dataStore, qName, List.of(new QName(geomColumn)), List.of(geometry), idFilter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static boolean updateTransaction(WFSDataStore dataStore, QName qName, List<QName> columns, List<Object> values, Filter filter) throws IOException {
    TransactionRequest transactionRequest = dataStore.getWfsClient().createTransaction();
    TransactionRequest.Update update = transactionRequest.createUpdate(qName, columns, values, filter);
    transactionRequest.add(update);

    return transaction(dataStore, transactionRequest, TransactionResponse::getUpdatedCount) > 0;
}

public static <T> T transaction(WFSDataStore dataStore, TransactionRequest transactionRequest, Function<TransactionResponse, T> action) throws IOException {
    TransactionResponse response =
        dataStore
            .getWfsClient()
            .issueTransaction(transactionRequest);
    
    return action.apply(response);
}

WFS 1.1.0
When using WFS 1.1.0, the request is sent and updates are performed. The response comes that the line has been updated, but POLYGON EMPTY is saved in the geometry field
WFS 2.0.0
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:Transaction 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:bis="https://bis.org/bis" 
        xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" 
        xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
        xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        handle="GeoTools 32.0(1e7dfc3f76d52f53b7a7b0af9bc02d5a1c321535) WFS 2.0.0 DataStore @PC-0017#1" 
        releaseAction="ALL" 
        service="WFS" 
        version="2.0.0">
    <wfs:Update inputFormat="application/gml+xml; version=3.2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" typeName="bis:test">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:ValueReference action="replace">geometry</wfs:ValueReference>
            <wfs:Value>
                <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:coordinates>30.262776196255125,59.93954262728195 30.262907623301622,59.93958105131431 30.262941029017526,59.9395526213441 30.262956789606722,59.93953962130284 30.263027460562363,59.939488541678394 30.262897264629483,59.93944742258056 30.262776196255125,59.93954262728195</gml:coordinates>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
            </wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <fes:Filter>
            <fes:ResourceId rid="test.07b9c1b9-c134-4025-845e-9372e09d1e05"/>
        </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>

A response comes from the GeoServer:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="2.0.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 
  http://localhost:8484/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidValue" locator="geometry">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Invalid value for property geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

You can view the code and run the test: GITHUB

You need to check the log file to see what is causing that error (as I said on stackoverflow)

@IanTurton There are no errors in the logs on the geotools side. On Geoserver, if WFS version 2, then the error: org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Invalid value for property geometry. If version 1.1, then there are no errors at all, just empty geometry. I made a project that uses testcontainers, just run the test, please look at github.

@IanTurton I think the problem is that in the PropertyTypeBinding class, gml2.GMLConfiguration is used when formatting the geometry. If you change to gml3.GMLConfiguration, then the geometry format becomes correct
